# How to rotate text in React Native vertically

Tags: react-native

As shown in the image, i need to place the texts 'left', 'right' & 'botton' vertically, excatly like as shown in the picture

PLEASE REFER THE LINK, AS I CAN'T POST AN IMAGE!

image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEivI.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try transform style to rotate the text here is the example:

```
    <Text
       style={{
         transform: [{ rotate: "90deg" }],
      }}
    >
       Your Text
   </Text>
```

**Note** you can adjust the font rotation by angle like `90deg` for clockwise rotation and `-90deg` for anticlock rotation

Comment: already tried that but text breaks, anyways i found the solution. Thanks!